# how to get users's information by name location using facebook python sdk

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Now I am trying to get the users' information (e.g., name, company, email) using the python sdk by using the users' names and location. Below is my code (which only can use name to search)

```
import facebook
import requests

graph=facebook.GraphAPI($authtoken$)
data = graph.request('/search?q=angel&type=user')
print (data)
```

but it can only use name to search, and the result only shows a list of customers that with only name and id.

I am not sure:

> 1. how to use name and location to get the users' list together
> 2. how to get users' full information, not just userid

Comment: both points are not possible. you only get location and more information by authorizing a user with the correct permissions. it does not matter if the information is public on facebook.com, btw.

Comment: what does by authorizing a user with the correct permissions? does it mean if I do not have a permission to the user's information, then I can only get user id?

Comment: @luschn is there anyway I can achieve this 2 problems?

Comment: no, there is no way. without user authorization, you can only get id and name.